# Set vim colorscheme in command line

Tags: vim

Is there a way to set the colorscheme in the command line for vim, so

```
vim "+colorscheme desert"
```

It's because I want to run the vundle installer from the command line and it fails to start vim because the colorscheme in the vimrc is not available until after vundle has run.

Comment: if the colorscheme was not available, you can start vim and do vundle update/install anyway. after your bundles get updated, next time you start vim, the colorsch should be there.

Comment: That's my point, I run the vundle installer from the command line, it's automated because I set up my workspaces in a automated fashion.

Comment: This sounds like you really just want to suppress the error via `:silent! colorscheme desert` in your `~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly check for the existence of the colorscheme, e.g.

```
if ! empty(globpath(&rtp, 'colors/desert.vim'))
    colorscheme desert
endif
```

But I would rather just silence the error:

```
:silent! colorscheme desert
```

Of course, you can also set the colorscheme from the command line:

```
$ vim -c "colorscheme desert"
```

But I would rather optimize your setup for the common case (of existing colorscheme), not the special base of a bare system.